# Filter Stack Exchange homepage

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I'd love to be able to slap some quick filters on my homepage on Stack Exchange.

**Simplest form**: Next to each site at the top right, put a little eyeball that I can close and open, with a "close/open all" eyeball at the very top. Then, if I just want to quickly see new/hot/whatever questions from the Trilogy, I can quickly close all and then open the Trilogy eyeballs, four clicks to seeing an aggregate of the Trilogy questions.

**More Complex**: Allow me to save "views". So, say I wanted to create a view of three loosely-related Stack Exchange sites. I'd:

1. Close all eyeballs
2. Open eyeballs for "Cooking", "Bicycles" and "Home Improvement"
3. Name that view "Domestic" (or something)

The view would appear as a link down below the site list. When I clicked the link it would toggle all the eyeballs to create the correct view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that sounds like the tag-sets functionality; [start here](https://stackexchange.com/filters), but you can define your own set of filters on particular (or all) sites. And have it via e-mail, RSS, or just a link. Is that far from what you had in mind?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think they had any of that when I asked this question... Awesome!

Comment: The link you reference: http://stackexchange.com/filters/popular no longer works.

Comment: @rene I think that cross network favorite tags filter is the correct place, maybe even what "popular" used to be. :)