# Let's disambiguate / burninate [filter]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request, burninate-request

The [filter](/questions/tagged/filter) tag, used on 27 questions has no excerpt or wiki, and it's used in quite a few different situations, see below. I think we should get rid of it, but slowly, in order not to flood the homepage with edits.

#### Post quality filters:

(these can probably be retagged to [quality-filter](/questions/tagged/quality-filter))

- [Any way to work around filtering of links containing numeric addresses?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198209/any-way-to-work-around-filtering-of-links-containing-numeric-addresses)
- [Can the warning system for question titles adapt to warn about tone in answers and comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139795/can-the-warning-system-for-question-titles-adapt-to-warn-about-tone-in-answers-a)
- [Do not force editors of old questions to change a title with problem words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115538/do-not-force-editors-of-old-questions-to-change-a-title-with-problem-words)
- [Trigger "don't do this" message if question starts/ends with filler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115038/trigger-dont-do-this-message-if-question-starts-ends-with-filler)
- [Cannot edit question without also changing the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108069/cannot-edit-question-without-also-changing-the-title)
- [Please remove the s/!/?/ title filter from Metaǃ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102807/please-remove-the-s-title-filter-from-meta%c7%83)
- [Should we warn on "should"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/should-we-warn-on-should)
- [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

#### Search / general question navigation:

(these can probably be tagged [search](/questions/tagged/search) or [tag-search](/questions/tagged/tag-search), if they aren't already)

- [Filtering, sorting, showing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178212/filtering-sorting-showing)
- [Combination of noanswers and mytags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/combination-of-noanswers-and-mytags)
- [filter answers after search when clicking on label (include/exclude)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135845/filter-answers-after-search-when-clicking-on-label-include-exclude)
- [Filter for Objective C only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117082/filter-for-objective-c-only)
- [votes 'range' filter in viewing questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111793/votes-range-filter-in-viewing-questions)
- [Conditional Filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105025/conditional-filters)
- [How can I format a query so that search matches tags by OR instead of AND?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79248/how-can-i-format-a-query-so-that-search-matches-tags-by-or-instead-of-and)
- [Is it possible to view questions in SO without comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48312/is-it-possible-to-view-questions-in-so-without-comments)
- [Filter "Questions" based on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/filter-questions-based-on-topic)
- [How can I browse community wiki posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14401/how-can-i-browse-community-wiki-posts)

#### Review queue filters

(we could make a separate [review-filter](/questions/tagged/review-filter) tag, but I'm not sure if it's necessary; otherwise, we need to make sure they're tagged [review](/questions/tagged/review))

- [Review queue audit doesn’t take current filter mode into account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324050/review-queue-audit-doesn-t-take-current-filter-mode-into-account)
- [Filter by tag in Close Votes review gives question without that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239326/filter-by-tag-in-close-votes-review-gives-question-without-that-tag)
- [Is it possible to customize suggested edit reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199922/is-it-possible-to-customize-suggested-edit-reviews)
- [Apply filter to exclude particular tag in close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/apply-filter-to-exclude-particular-tag-in-close-vote-queue)

#### StackExchange.com filters

([filter](/questions/tagged/filter) → [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters))

- [Filter revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183908/filter-revision-history)
- [Filter Stack Exchange homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63888/filter-stack-exchange-homepage)
- I've also proposed [stackexchange-filter](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-filter) (13 questions, no excerpt/wiki) to be a synonym for [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters) (152 questions), you can vote for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/synonyms).

#### Others:

- [Sensitivity of auto-question block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149760/sensitivity-of-auto-question-block) ([post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) instead of [ban](/questions/tagged/ban) and [filter](/questions/tagged/filter))
- [Careers 2.0 Search Function: Why is Joel Score not included as a search filter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144070/careers-2-0-search-function-why-is-joel-score-not-included-as-a-search-filter) (off-topic, [filter](/questions/tagged/filter) can be removed)

Any thoughts? Am I missing something - there might be a good reason to keep this tag?

Comment: I retagged the questions listed under *stackexchange filters*.

Comment: Thank you, I've tackled the [review] ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to various users, the [filter](/questions/tagged/filter) tag is now burninated. All that remains of my original request is the proposal for [stackexchange-filter](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-filter) (13 questions, no excerpt/wiki) to be a synonym for [tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters) (154 questions); you can vote for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/synonyms).

Comment: Looks like that has now been synonymized/merged as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great proposal, but I would refrain from creating a review-filter tag, as it's use is too minimal.

For your *Others* category I'd opt to delete the closed question on the [Joel Score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144070/careers-2-0-search-function-why-is-joel-score-not-included-as-a-search-filter), as it is an unanswered duplicate to a question with an authoritative answer. I think that would be more appropriate then bumping it with an edit.

[The other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149760/sensitivity-of-auto-question-block) I already re-tagged, as to make a slow start with this burn, as I observe no real objections against your proposal. I also voted to close it as off-topic, as it specifically relates to SO only.